# PrincipalPermission on Method doesn't work if applied to Class

Tags: c#, .net, principalpermission

I have code that looks something like this:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "RoleA")]
class Foo
{
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "RoleB")]
    public static bool Bar()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

If I try to run `Foo.Bar();` it will fail if I don't have RoleA, but never checks for RoleB. It works regardless of whether or not I have RoleB, as long as I have RoleA.

If I remove `[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "RoleA")]` from the class definition then it checks for RoleB as expected.

I've searched around and found this exact problem mentioned on two different SO questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128186/code-is-ignoring-principalpermission-attribute) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289100/principalpermission-on-methods-is-being-ignored-when-there-is-principalpermissio#comment88422876_33289100)) with no answer in either case. One has a comment that points to an old Microsoft Connect link that supposedly contains the answer, but there are no comments or answers that actually say what the problem is.

I would really, really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple PrincipalPermissionAttribute Demands are combined using OR, so in your case:

- RoleA can construct an instance of the class and call any method.
- RoleB can call the method Bar, but can't call the constructor.

Because of this, your code is equivalent to:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "RoleA")]
class Foo
{
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "RoleA")]
    public Foo()
    {
    }

    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "RoleA")]
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "RoleB")]
    public static bool Bar()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you want to combine Demands using AND, you should specify Role= as a comma-separated list, e.g. "RoleA,RoleB".  Or use SecurityAction.Deny appropriately.

The example below illustrates this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var aPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("AUser", ""), new[] {"RoleA"});
        var bPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("BUser", ""), new[] { "RoleB" });
        var abPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("ABUser", ""), new[] { "RoleB", "RoleA" });

        // AB can do anything
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = abPrincipal;
        var sc = new SecureClass();
        TryConstruct();
        TryBMethod(sc);
        TryABMethod(sc);

        // What can A do?
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = aPrincipal;
        TryConstruct();
        TryBMethod(sc);
        TryABMethod(sc);

        // What can B do?
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = bPrincipal;
        TryConstruct();
        TryBMethod(sc);
        TryABMethod(sc);

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void TryConstruct()
    {
        try
        {
            var sc = new SecureClass();
        }
        catch(SecurityException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Constructor SecurityException for " + Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
        }
    }
    static void TryBMethod(SecureClass sc)
    {
        try
        {
            sc.RoleBMethod();
        }
        catch (SecurityException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RoleBMethod SecurityException for " + Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
        }
    }
    static void TryABMethod(SecureClass sc)
    {
        try
        {
            sc.RoleABMethod();
        }
        catch (SecurityException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RoleABMethod SecurityException for " + Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
        }
    }

}

[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role ="RoleA")]
class SecureClass
{
    public SecureClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In constructor using " + Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
    }

    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "RoleB")]
    public void RoleBMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In RoleBMethod using " + Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
    }

    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "RoleA,RoleB")]
    public void RoleABMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In RoleBMethod using " + Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
    }

}
```

Comment: I was going through reference source for PrincipalPermissionAttribute but couldn't find where it ORs it. I'm wondering if, using a custom attribute, I can override something somewhere to force an AND.

Comment: @Wayne, an attribute in itself doesn't do anything, so you won't find anything in the `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` reference source.  Basically the CAS in the CLR must presumably evaluate all active `PrincipalPermissionAttribute`'s before executing a method, and do its stuff.  I personally wouldn't attempt a custom attribute; why not just use comma-separated roles?

Comment: I ended up solving my issue with a custom version of PrincipalPermissionAttribute and PrincipalPermission, and forcing the Demand on the method permission regardless of whether or not the class has one. Thanks for pointing my brain in the right direction.